# We are off on Saturdays and Sundays

Tags: word-usage

If someone wants to say that "We have Saturdays and Sundays off", is it okay to use:

> We are off on Saturdays and Sundays.

Is the use of "we are off" natural?

Comment: Yes. https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/day-off

Comment: @RonaldSole doesn't it sound like "we take Saturdays and Sundays off work" rather than "we have Saturdays and Sundays off."?

Comment: Both expressions are common and idiomatic. Adding **work** makes it more specific. For example, one can also be **off duty** or **off sick**.

Comment: For your *specific* context, native Anglophones are far more likely to say ***We don't work weekends.***

Comment: ...saying ***We get [the] weekends off*** does indeed imply you're working for a particularly harsh employer who thinks his workers should be *grateful* for such a "concession" - most "normal" employers would think *they* should be grateful if their employees are prepared to work weekends (for a higher "unsocial hours" rate of pay). So you are quite right to raise that point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable and will be understood as colloquial English.

> We take Saturdays and Sundays off work

"Take off" implies that it wouldn't be usual to have them off, but your original suggestion also implies that.

It really depends what you are trying to say. If you always have the weekend off it might be less ambiguous to say:

> We don't work on Weekends/ We don't work Saturdays and Sundays

---

**Off** can also be idiomatic for leaving. E.g.

> We are off on holiday on Saturday

or

> A: When do you leave?
>
> B: We are off on Saturday

[Source: The Free Dicitonary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off)

Comment: Hi I had another question: > **We were quite a way back stuck in traffic yesterday.** 
 _____________________________________________ Actually it is about a few people who take the same bus each day and the bus travels the same route each day. Yesterday they got to their stop late because they were held up by traffic and today they got to their stop on time and thus said this, as at this time yesterday they were stuck in traffic. **Does this sentence sound natural to you? Most of the people don't find it natural.…**

Comment: I understand it, but I agree it's not natural. Try "We were held up in/by traffic yesterday".